# Generation of sublists from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a string list consisting of alternating sequences of letters and digit characters.  I would like to join the letter sequences and convert the digit characters into numbers composing a sublist of integers:

```
lis = {"a","bc","0","14","2","d","e","f","3","wx","z","r","st"}
```

I would like to obtain:

```
res = {{"abc"},{0,14,2},{"def"},{3},{"wxzrst"}}
```

Moving back and forth from symbols, numbers and string representation of digits makes for many lines of what must be extraneous code.  I would be grateful for (and curious to see) ideas for economic code for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
If[StringMatchQ[#[[1]], NumberString], FromDigits /@ #, {StringJoin@#}] & /@ 
 SplitBy[lis, StringMatchQ[NumberString]]
```

> {{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}

or

```
SplitBy[If[StringMatchQ[#, NumberString], FromDigits@#, #] & /@ lis, Head] /.
 {s__String} :> {StringJoin@s}
```

> {{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}

or

```
SequenceReplace[lis, 
  {{s__String?(Not@*StringMatchQ[NumberString] )} :> {StringJoin[s]} , 
  {n__String?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])} :> FromDigits /@ {n} } ]
```

> {{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}

Answer (score 6):

Here's another variation similar to @kglr's:

```
SplitBy[
    List @@ StringExpression @@ StringReplace[lis, n:NumberString :> FromDigits[n]],
    Head
]
```

> {{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lis = {"a", "bc", "0", "14", "2", "d", "e", "f", "3", "wx", "z", "r", 
   "st"};
t1 = SplitBy[lis, StringMatchQ[NumberString]];
```

> {{"a", "bc"}, {"0", "14", "2"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"3"}, {"wx", "z",
> "r", "st"}}

Every other list has entries that will convert to numbers. To avoid verbosity later, define the following patterns:

```
listOfNumbers = {s__?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])};
listOfStrings = {s__String};
```

The idea is to `MapAt` the appropriate function at the correct sublist location. `ToExpression` gets applied to sublists that match the `NumberString` pattern. The resulting list has string only sublists that are catenated.

```
(MapAt[ToExpression, t1
   , Position[t1, listOfNumbers]]) // 
 MapAt[List@*Apply[StringJoin], #
   , Position[#, listOfStrings]] &
```

> {{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}

*Advantage*

The advantage is that now such a conversion can be applied to a selected number of desired locations. e.g., first two positions only or every other position by filtering the output from `Position`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
Riffle[
    Map[List @* StringJoin, SequenceCases[lis, {__ ? LetterQ}]],
    Map[ToExpression @* Most,
        SequenceCases[lis, {__ ? DigitQ, _ ? LetterQ}]
    ]
 ]

(*{{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
num = StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &;   

fun[{x_?num}] := ToExpression[x]
fun[x_] := StringJoin[x]

SplitBy[fun /@ Split[lis, !num[#1] && !num[#2] &], Head]
```

{{"abc"}, {0, 14, 2}, {"def"}, {3}, {"wxzrst"}}